# Given a censored string and a string of the censored vowels, return the original uncensored string

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>
  var immutable = "";
  var count = 0;
  function uncensor(str1, str2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str1[i] == "*") {
        immutable =
          str1.slice(0, i) +
          str2[count] +
          str1.slice(i + 1, str1.length - 1);
        count++;
      }
    }
    return immutable;
  }

  document.write(uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*?", "eeioeo"));

  // uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*?", "eeioeo")
  </script>
```

My logic is updating the variable immutable every time there is a `"*"`. So by the end of the loop all the `"*"` will be replaced by the characters in str2 one by one.

I expect the result to be `"Where did my vowels go?`"

The output is none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to iterate through input and capture result in an array:

```js
  var immutable = "";
  var count = 0;
  function uncensor(str1, str2) {
    let result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
      if (str1[i] == "*") {
        result.push(str2[count++]);
      } else {
        result.push(str1[i]);
      }
    }
    return result.join("");
  }

console.log(uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*?", "eeioeo"));
```

EDIT: the fact that string is [immutable](https://www.sitepoint.com/immutability-javascript/) means that every time you use `splice` or `+` character you create a new string. If you want to use your approach with `splice` you need to concatenate parts of `str` with characters from `str2` like below however the upper solution should be a way more performant:

```js
  var result = "";
  var count = 0;
  var lastCensored = 0;
  function uncensor(str1, str2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
      if (str1[i] == "*") {
        result +=
          str1.slice(lastCensored, i) +
          str2[count++];
        lastCensored = i + 1;
      }
    }
    return result + str1.slice(lastCensored, str1.length);
  }

  document.write(uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*?", "eeioeo"));

  // uncensor("Wh*r* d*d my v*w*ls g*?", "eeioeo")
```

Comment: hi！ good to see you again! this works but I really want to know what's wrong with my code, is it because of the immutable string again?

Comment: @JiangYuxin in your code your building a new string `immutable` `str.length` times while what you really want to achieve is to build a string once - that's why I suggest preparing an array of dynamically evaluated characters instead of using `splice` this time

Comment: Yeah I really prefer your solution but is it possible for you to debug my code too? I know it's inefficient now but fixing the code can help me understand the concepts better. : )

Comment: So can I say that it's not possible to update a string in a for loop? the only way is to create a new string to store the information updated everytime?

Comment: @JiangYuxin it is not possible to modify existing string - you always create a new one. Getting back to your code - every time you encounter `"*"` you replace `immutable` variable while you should be really concatenating that final string - take a look at my 2nd approach and `+=` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `.replace`:

```
 function uncensor(str, v) {
   return str.replace(/\*/g, () => ([, ...v] = v)[0]);
 }
```